# Azure DevOps multi-stage pipeline, trigger specific stage by specific artifact change

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

The multi stage pipeline looks like this.
A->B->C

Stage A consume artifact a
Stage B consume artifact b
Stage C consume artifact c

Artifact can be repository/pipeline...

How to trigger only Stage B when b artifact change ?

Comment: Hi @Janusz Nowak. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you need kind of trigger per stage which is not possible to achieve at the moment. Please check [this topic on developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/578950/re-run-a-single-stage-in-a-multi-stage-pipeline.html)

> Sorry I should have clarified a bit more. I don't think that triggers will solve all use cases, but having triggers on stages would at least allow you to have the following:
>
> 1. Stage A has trigger /src/appA
> 2. Stage B has trigger /src/appB
>
> If you commited (script, code, etc.) to /src/appB, it should use previous artifacts and only build appB and further if requested.

This is mentioned in the comment and left without feedback from MS, however it is not possible with existing Azure DevOps functionalities.